# How can I start a LazyList by showing the last element in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

**Background**

- I'm creating a chat application and I want the latest messages to be shown to the user when they launch the screen.
- I'm also using sticky headers to show the dates, which I group by in my viewmodel.

**Attempts**

- Setting `reverseLayout = true` in my LazyColumn was amazing but I had the `stickyHeaders` showing up as "stickyFooters" instead, which is not ideal
- Setting `scrollToItem` works exactly as it should, BUT it's firstly showing the first items and then going to the last one, which causes an annoying flicker every time the user opens the screen.

```
scrollState.scrollToItem(
    scrollState.layoutInfo.totalItemsCount,
)
```

**Some Code**

```
LazyColumn(
        modifier = modifier,
//        reverseLayout = true,
        state = scrollState,
    ) {
        items.forEach { sectionedListItem ->
            stickyHeader {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                        .padding(vertical = if (sectionedListItem.sectionTitle == "") 0.dp else 8.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    text = sectionedListItem.sectionTitle
                )
            }
            items(
                count = sectionedListItem.items.size,
                key = { sectionedListItem.items[it].id },
                itemContent = {
                    val message = remember { sectionedListItem.items[it] }
                    TSDMessage(Modifier, message, userId == message.authorId, maxWidth)
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

**Question**

How can I start by showing the last elements in Jetpack Compose, without having the stickyHeaders showing under or by having the annoying flickering delay of `scrollToItem`?

More code and/or screenshots can be provided if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can take your list and order it first. For instance, something like:

```
val orderedList = sectionedListItem.sortedByDescending {it.items}
```

and then pass your orderedList into your LazyColumn.

PS: It is recommended to perform the sorting in your viewModel.